# VS2015 and Xamarin Cross Platform

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, cross-platform

Today I started my first Android App using **Xamarin and VS2015 (Cross platform)** after Compiling App with no error, i got the popup stating Error "**you were previously added to the Hyper-V Administrators security group, but the permission have not taken effect. Please sign out of your computer for the permission to take effect**"

i tried to google the error but unable to find the solution. some place i got to know i need to apply right \ permission using InitialStore.xml. i search for the process to get it done using the following path programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\ but was unable to find the desired file. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to sign off and sign in, as the message requests.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2014/06/11/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-vupdated/

Hyper-V related settings are also changed, so you no longer need to touch InitialStore.xml file.